# Realloc Arguments

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am implementing Stack using arrays with the below code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Stack{
int top;
int capacity;
int *array;
};

struct Stack *createStack()
{
        struct Stack *stack=malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
        stack->top=-1;
        stack->capacity=1;
        stack->array=malloc(sizeof(sizeof(int)*stack->capacity));
}
void doubleStack(struct Stack *stack)
{
        stack->capacity=stack->capacity*2;
        stack->array=realloc(stack,stack->capacity);
}
void push( struct Stack *stack , int data)
{
        if(stack->top==(stack->capacity)-1)
                doubleStack(stack);
        stack->array[++stack->top]=data;
}
```

My doubt is, when `doubleStack` is called once the Stack is full, 
Should I use `stack->array` as the first argument of the `realloc()` or `stack` as the first argument of the `realloc()`?

Well I think `stack->array` should be passed. As we need to reallocate only that portion of the memory.

But accidentally I passed `stack` and that also seemed to work. Please advise.

Comment: `stack->array=realloc(stack,stack->capacity);} -->>
` `stack->array=realloc(stack->array,sizeof stack->array[0] * stack->capacity);}
`

Comment: Funny: until now, all three answers have failed to see the omission of `sizeof(int)` in the size expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass to `realloc` a pointer to the array that you wish to extend. Since `stack` is not an array that you wish to extend, and `stack->array` is, you should pass `stack->array` as the first parameter.

However, you should store the result of `realloc` in a separate variable and do `NULL` check.

> If the function fails to allocate the requested block of memory, a
>   null pointer is returned, and the memory block pointed to by argument
>   ptr is not deallocated (it is still valid, and with its contents
>   unchanged).

Otherwise you risk creating a memory leak:

```
int *tmp = realloc(stack->array, stack->capacity);
if (tmp) {
    stack->array = tmp;
} else {
    ... // Deal with the allocation error here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're correctly thought,

```
  stack->array=realloc(stack,stack->capacity);
```

should **atleast** be

```
  stack->array=realloc(stack->array,stack->capacity);
```

Otherwise, if successful, you'll be `free()`-ing up `stack` itself and then you'll end up accessing it. That invokes  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Many things "seem" to work once you've got UB.

That said, from the usage point of view,

```
 p = realloc(p, q);
```

kind of code is very bad, as if `realloc()` fails, it won't modify the `p` which has been passed as an argument, but due to the direct assignment of the return value of `realloc()` to `p`, the `p` will be set to `NULL`, losing the actual stored pointer.

Tip: Always use a temporary pointer to collect the return value of `realloc()`, then check for `realloc()` success and in case ofg success, assign the newly returned pointer to the pointer which has been passed to `realloc()`.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip Sourav

Answer (score 1):

First of all function `push` is wrong

```
void push( struct Stack *stack , int data)
{
        if(stack->top==(stack->capacity)-1)
                doubleStack(stack);
        stack->array[++stack->top]=data;
}
```

Initially `top` is set to 1 and `capacity` is also set to 1.

So this condition

```
if(stack->top==(stack->capacity)-1)
```

yields `false` and the following statement

```
stack->array[++stack->top]=data;
```

is executed. It writes to memory `stack->array[2]` that is beyond the allocated array.

I think initially `top` should be set to 0. And the function should be defined the following way

```
void push( struct Stack *stack , int data )
{
        if ( stack->top != stack->capacity || doubleStack( stack ) )
        {
            stack->array[stack->top++] = data;
        } 
}
```

In this case you can simply define a function that reports whether a stack is empty the following way

```
int empty( struct Stack *stack ) { return stack->top == 0; }
```

As for the function `doubleStack` then it should be defined the following way

```
int doubleStack(struct Stack *stack)
{
        int success = 0;

        int new_capacity = 2 * stack->capacity;

        int *tmp = = realloc( stack->array, new_capacity * sizeof( int ) );

        if ( ( success = tmp != NULL ) ) 
        {
            stack->capacity = new_capacity;
            stack->array = tmp;
        }

        return success
}
```

Take into account that I changed the return type of the function from `void` to `int`.
Also I used an intermediate varaible `new_capacity`. If the reallocation fails the current capacity will not be changed

Comment: Initially top is not set to 1 it is set to -1 see using **stack->top=-1**

Comment: @Rohit Saluja I thought that it is initialized by 1. Nevertheless only the implementation of doubleStack shown by me is correct.:) The same can be said about function push. That is in any case my post is the most uuseful.:)